# When using HTML Media Capture, is it possible to disable certain actions?

Tags: html, media, capture

When using HTML Media Capture, is it possible to disable certain actions (such as "retake" or "use existing video")?

W3C Specification does not state anything but I just wanted to know if there are some tricks out there.

Link to W3C Specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/

Answer (score 0):

You can not disable "retaking".

You should be able to disable selecting an existing file ("Photo Library" on iOS and "Documents" on Android) through [HTML Media Capture's `capture` attribute](https://blog.addpipe.com/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/) but it's only supported by Android. No support in iOS6-10.